# How to find specific parent node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I have to convert docx to xml and using DOM to find parent node of specific.

For example

```
   <chapter>
       <title>
           <label>Chapter 1
           </label>
       </title>
       <para>This is chapterpara <a id="book"/>
       </para>
   </chapter>
```

Here i want to find anchor node's super parent's child(title node).

I knew the anchor node reference by getting

```
 var itemanchor=ItemElement.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

How to traverse specific parent node from the above reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not used DOM / XML in Node, but in browser DOM you could use `itemAnchor[0].parentNode.parentNode.firstChild`

Comment: @Vanarajan Is my answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use need to use `createDocumentFragment()` method to create fake document, then appending you html to fake document and get target element from it. See this example

```js
var HTML =
'<chapter>\
    <title>\
        <label>Chapter1</label>\
    </title>\
    <para>\
        This is chapterpara\
        <a id="book" href="mySiteAddress" />\
    </para>\
</chapter>';

var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = HTML;

var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
docfrag.appendChild(element);

var href = docfrag.getElementById("book").getAttribute("href");
document.write(href);
```

If you want to get other element, must get element from `docfrag`.